# Buscar recursivamente un objecto interno comparando un atributo

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando las [webix](https://docs.webix.com/index.html) para una GUI; para aprovechar sus ventajas, la GUI se define en un archivo aparte, `/gui.js`.

Una vez cargado, tengo que hacer algunas transformaciones en esa GUI. Establecer algunos atributos, límites, funciones de respuesta a eventos, ... Puesto que necesito cosas que están en otros archivos, **no** puedo establecer estos valores en el propio `gui.js`; tengo que hacerlo **después** de cargar toda la página, usando `window.onload`.

**Todos** los elementos gráficos *relevantes* de esa GUI son objetos, y se distinguen por su atributo `id`. Algunos de ellos pueden, a su vez, contener objetos internos. Estos se localizan en 2 formas:

1. Una lista. El atributo, en el objeto padre, es uno de `rows:`, `cols:`, `cells:` o `elements:`. Es lo mas normal.
2. Un atributo especial. En este caso, **siempre** es `body:`.

Copio el `gui.js` completo, para que se entienda bien:

```
const MainView = { id: 'MAIN', rows: [
    { view: 'select', id: 'ADDRESS', value: 1, label: 'Address:', options: [ ], labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', disabled: true },
    { view: 'select', id: 'SENDER', label: 'Sender:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', value: 1 },
    { view: 'select', id: 'TARGET', label: 'Target:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', value: 1 },
    { view: 'counter', id: 'INTERVAL', label: 'Interval:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right' },
    { cols: [
        { view: 'button', id: 'UPLOAD', label: 'Select CFG file', width: 150 },
        { width: 25 },
        { view: 'label', label: '<none selected>', id: 'CONFIG' }
      ]
    },
    { cols: [
        { minWidth: 50 },
        { view: 'button', type: 'form', value: 'Start', id: 'START', width: 150, disabled: true },
        { minWidth: 50 },
        { view: 'button', type: 'danger', value: 'Stop', id: 'STOP', width: 150, disabled: true },
        { minWidth: 50 }
      ]
    },
    { view: 'list', id: 'LOG', template: '#timestamp# :: #msg#', data: [ ] }
  ]
};

const Layout = { rows: [
    { view: 'toolbar', cols: [
        { view: 'button', id: 'QUIT', value: 'Quit' }, //, image: 'images/quit.png' },
        { view: 'button', id: 'RESTART', value: 'Restart' }, //, image: 'images/restart.png' },
        { view: 'button', id: 'ASPECT', value: 'Aspect' } //, image: 'images/aspect.png' }
      ]
    },
    { view: 'tabview', id: 'TABVIEW', cells: [
        { header: 'Main', body: MainView }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Quiero automatizar el proceso, de forma que utilizo una objeto cuyos atributos son los `id` a *externder*, y el valor de dichos atributos es a su vez un objeto con los atributos reales. Con el código se ve mejor:

```
function createGui( ) {
  const changes = {
    ADDRESS: { 
      on: { onChange: ( ) => this.onAddressChanged }
    }
  };
  var curr;

  for( let key in changes ) if( changes.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    curr = locateWidget( Layout, key );
    Object.assign( curr, changes[key] );
  }

  function locateWidget( layout, wid ) {
    var curr;

    if( Array.isArray( layout ) ) {
      layout.forEach( function( ele ) {
        if( typeof( ele ) == 'object' && ( ele !== null ) ) {
          curr = locateWidget( ele, wid );
          if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        }
      } );
    } else {
      if( ( 'id' in layout ) && ( layout.id === wid ) ) return layout;

      if( Array.isArray( layout.rows ) ) {
        curr = locateWidget( layout.rows, wid );
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.cols ) ) {
        curr = locateWidget( layout.cols, wid );
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.cells ) ) {
        curr = locateWidget( layout.cells, wid );
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.elements ) ) {
        curr = locateWidget( layout.elements, wid );
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
      }

      if( ( typeof( layout.body ) == 'object' ) && ( layout.body !== null ) ) {
        curr = locateWidget( layout.body, wid );
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En el código anterior, la función interna `locateWidget( )` **falla** estrepitosamente; **no** encuentra el elemento interno, mostrando un error por consola.

El resultado esperado: al salir de la función `createGui( )`, la variable `Layout.rows[1].cells[0].body.on` debería ser `{ onChange: ( ) => this.onAddressChanged }`. Sin embargo, obtengo un error en consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contexto de la función createGui? No veo como la llamas para que this no sea undefined o que onAddressChanged exista. Además creo que le faltan los paréntesis...

Comment: Estas buscando el id `ADDRESS` que no esta presente en tu objeto `LAYOUT`, por lo que la funcion regresa `undefined`.

Comment: @alanfcm `ADDRESS` está en `MainView.rows[1]`, que a su vez está *enlazado* (es un `Object`, se usan *referencias* a ellos) a `Layout.rows[1].cells[0].body`. La función **debería** de encontrarlo, recorriendo toda la jerarquía. Pero no lo hace :-(

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores.  Primero, tienes declarada dos veces la variable `curr`.  Segundo, necesitas chequear primero si la variable esta definida antes de volver a asignarle valor.  Tercero, para que la recursion funcione, necesitas retornar el valor al final de la funcion.  Por ultimo,  te faltaba un nivel para accesar el valor que quieres.  La forma correcta seria algo asi:

```js
const MainView = { id: 'MAIN', rows: [
    { view: 'select', id: 'ADDRESS', value: 1, label: 'Address:', options: [ ], labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', disabled: true },
    { view: 'select', id: 'SENDER', label: 'Sender:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', value: 1 },
    { view: 'select', id: 'TARGET', label: 'Target:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right', value: 1 },
    { view: 'counter', id: 'INTERVAL', label: 'Interval:', labelWidth: 100, labelAlign: 'right' },
    { cols: [
        { view: 'button', id: 'UPLOAD', label: 'Select CFG file', width: 150 },
        { width: 25 },
        { view: 'label', label: '<none selected>', id: 'CONFIG' }
      ]
    },
    { cols: [
        { minWidth: 50 },
        { view: 'button', type: 'form', value: 'Start', id: 'START', width: 150, disabled: true },
        { minWidth: 50 },
        { view: 'button', type: 'danger', value: 'Stop', id: 'STOP', width: 150, disabled: true },
        { minWidth: 50 }
      ]
    },
    { view: 'list', id: 'LOG', template: '#timestamp# :: #msg#', data: [ ] }
  ]
};

const Layout = { rows: [
    { view: 'toolbar', cols: [
        { view: 'button', id: 'QUIT', value: 'Quit' }, //, image: 'images/quit.png' },
        { view: 'button', id: 'RESTART', value: 'Restart' }, //, image: 'images/restart.png' },
        { view: 'button', id: 'ASPECT', value: 'Aspect' } //, image: 'images/aspect.png' }
      ]
    },
    { view: 'tabview', id: 'TABVIEW', cells: [
        { header: 'Main', body: MainView }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function createGui( ) {
  const changes = {
    ADDRESS: { 
      on: { onChange: ( ) => this.onAddressChanged }
    }
  };
  var curr;

  for( let key in changes ) if( changes.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    curr = locateWidget( Layout, key );
    Object.assign( curr, changes[key] );
  }
  
  function locateWidget( layout, wid ) {
    
    if( Array.isArray( layout ) ) {
      for (let ele of layout) {      
        if( typeof( ele ) == 'object' && ( ele !== null ) ) {          
          if( curr !== undefined ) {            
            return curr;
          } else {
            curr = locateWidget( ele, wid );
          }
        }
      } 
    } else {
      if( ( 'id' in layout ) && ( layout.id === wid ) ) return layout;

      if( Array.isArray( layout.rows ) ) {
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        curr = locateWidget( layout.rows, wid );
        
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.cols ) ) {
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        curr = locateWidget( layout.cols, wid );
        
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.cells ) ) {
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        curr = locateWidget( layout.cells, wid );
        
      }

      if( Array.isArray( layout.elements ) ) {
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        curr = locateWidget( layout.elements, wid );
        
      }

      if( ( typeof( layout.body ) == 'object' ) && ( layout.body !== null ) ) {
        if( curr !== undefined ) return curr;
        curr = locateWidget( layout.body, wid );
        
      }
    }
    return curr;
  }
}
createGui();
console.log(Layout.rows[1].cells[0].body.rows[0].on);
```

Comment: Creo que deberías modificar un poco la respuesta. Lo que indicas no afecta para nada (lo resolví hace un rato). Lo que **si** que afecta es, precisamente, lo que no indicas: al usar `forEach( )`, se recorre **todo** el array; el `return` dentro de la función pasada como argumento termina el procesado del elemento del array actual ... pero lo retornado se pierde :-)